# Ember.js - login example: Ember.run.later

Tags: ember.js

I copied this [login example](http://jsfiddle.net/workmanw/2znn2/) for my own needs. It runs fine. But I am asking myself: why do I need the `Ember.run.later(this, this._serverLogin, 100);` line? Like the comment said it is only for simulating the delay. Ok. But if I change it to this:

```
// Create the login controller
  MyApp.loginController = Ember.Object.create({
    username: '',
    password: '',
    isError: false,

    tryLogin: function() {
      if(this.get('username') === MyApp.USERNAME &&
         this.get('password') === MyApp.PASSWORD) {
        this.set('isError', false);
        this.set('username', '');
        this.set('password', '');
        MyApp.stateManager.send('loginSuccess');
      } else {
        this.set('isError', true);
        MyApp.stateManager.send('loginFail');
      }
    },
  });
```

without `Ember.run.later(this, this._serverLogin, 100);`, I get `Uncaught Error: <Ember.StateManager:ember270> could not respond to event loginSuccess in state loggedOut.awaitingCredentials.` So I thought probably I need this delay to get the stateManager changed before or somethign like that. But when I run the old code with `Ember.run.later(this, this._serverLogin, 0);` it still works. So, whats different? The [documentation of ember](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.run.html#method=.later) didnt gave any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `StateManager` is still in the early state setup process when calling a `sendEvent` (`loginSuccess`/`loginFailed`).

By delaying the event sending w/ `Ember.run.later`, your code is processed in a next run loop, and the state is properly setup.

---

That being said, you are using Ember in a very old fashion. You should have a look at the [state-of-the-art way to manage app routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes, after that I already implemented my Router like it is shown in the tutorial. Now I try to get both (my StateManager for loginViews and my Router) packed together. Could find a good example for that, so I tried it that way.